# How to make my GUI work

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone tell me on how the swing components drawn from the palette and put into the Jfame can work together? For example If a button pressed can the result show on the textArea, Or Can I drag some listed objects from the Jlist in my JFrame onto the JtextArea/JTabpanel?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this question is too vague to be answered here.

Comment: It sounds like you're using an IDE to develop your GUI; it would help to specify which IDE you're using.  Most GUI editors can create the method stubs, and some may even be able to handle drag-n-drop.  Maybe some of the other people here have more experience with that.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add an ActionListener to your button and in the actionPerformed method you can write the code to display a result in your JTextArea:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

More info on buttons:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

You can drag objects from a JList to another component (such as a JTextArea or JTable), but you would probably not drag them directly onto a JTabbedPane.  You'll have to code this behavior with the DnD API:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Rob has a pretty good answer.

Here's my 2 cents,

"For example If a button pressed can the result show on the textArea"

If you are using Netbeans, this is pretty quick and easy to do:

1. Double click your button.

   The IDE will jump to the actionPerformed method. (and put in the required boiler-plate code)
2. Place your code in the generated actionPerfored method

   e.g "jTextArea1.setText("hello world");"

I'd advise reading the swing tutorial on the sun website:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/